# implications of doing git add . when git add -u would suffice?

Tags: git

(Using Git 2.7.2)
If I after a day's work have updated a few tracked files that I want to commit, the appropriate command for staging would be `git add -u`. Right? But are there any ramifications of habitually doing `git add .` instead, just to cover for the possibility that I may have added a new file and don't want to forget to begin tracking it? Is there any downside to always doing `git add .`? Will I inflate the repo size or "pollute the database", etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git add .` will search through the current directory and subdirectories looking for files that can be added, and will then add them.

`git add -u` (with no path-spec) will, since git version 2.0, comb through the index to find files to add, which includes directories above `.` if you are in a sub-directory with your repository.  (In git versions predating 2.0, `git add -u` has an implied `.` at the end, so that it does *not* look at directories above `.`.)

You already noted that `git add .` will add new files that `git add -u` would not.  The fact that the `.` starts from the current directory (which may not be the top level) is the only other real difference here.  (If you have a very large work tree, you might see some CPU-time / disk-activity related differences as well due to the differing search strategies.)

Note that what goes into the repository on the next `git commit` is determined by the index (staging-area) contents, and you can inspect that at any time (with `git status` or `git ls-files`, for instance).  You don't really need to worry about repository bloat in most cases.  (The one case you would see temporary bloat is if `git add .` adds an enormous file, e.g., a giant binary or database or something, that you then `git rm --cached` and add to a `.gitignore` file.  This is because it's the `git add` step that actually writes the underlying blob object into the repository.  However, if the blob is unreferenced—as it will be after `git rm --cached`—it will go away on the next garbage collect that occurs after the `gc.pruneExpire` time, which in this case defaults to 14 days.)